# How to export JIRA comment

Tags: python, jira, jira-plugin, python-jira

I use Python JIRA library to export project content. Most of the fields are normal to catch, except the comments. Below is my codes, need help to point out what is the error. Why it come out with error: Thank you very much.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
    comments=item.fields.comment.comments
AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'comment'".
```

```py
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

jira = JIRA("http://jira-ep.ecp.priv")
block_size = 1000
block_num = 0
allissues = []

while True:
    start_idx = block_num * block_size
    issues = jira.search_issues(
        'project=PRJ0404 and type=DFM',
        start_idx,
        block_size
    )

    if len(issues) == 0:
        break

    block_num += 1

    for issue in issues:
        allissues.append(issue)

dfm = pd.DataFrame()

for item in allissues:
    d = {
        'key': item.key,
        'PCB': item.fields.customfield_10424,
        'Summary': item.fields.summary,
        'Severity': item.fields.customfield_10323,
        'Description': item.fields.description,
        'Reporter': item.fields.reporter,
        'Assignee': item.fields.assignee,
        'Create Stage': item.fields.customfield_10324,
        'Created Date': item.fields.created[0:10],
        'Updated Date': item.fields.updated[0:10],
        'Status': item.fields.status,
    }
    solution = ""
    comments = item.fields.comment.comments
    for comment in comments: # Get DFM comment filed content
        solution = comment.created[0:10] + 
            " " + 
            str(comment.author.name) + 
            ": " + 
            comment.body
    d = {'Solution': solution}
    dfm = dfm.append(d, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Where are those objects coming from, are you using a library? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: I use library jira. What document do you mean?

Comment: Please don't share code in comments, it's extremely difficult to read.

Comment: I post all my code for reference, I try the comments code before, it work, but fail in this codes... Don't know why

Comment: Problem has been solved now. I change the comments line to "comments=jira.comments(item)"